# How to edit colloquial questions

Tags: discussion

I recently edited [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27844/16008) and made some minor spelling corrections and tidying. However, the end of the question had this:

> Im thinking it would be a minuscule % but Im not sure. It could be a lot or a little but the idea is still sexy to me. Thank you guys.

Now, aside from giving me a good chuckle*, I was unsure of what to do. Even though it *clearly* doesn't add anything to the question, I felt it would go against **retaining the original author's intent**. I guess there's also a *slight* chance of being considered offensive.

What is the recommended practice for moderating this and similarly informal phrasing?

*The irony of using this colloquialism isn't lost on me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It could be a lot or a little but the idea is still sexy to me.

Personally, I would leave this alone. It's part of the user's manner of speech, and it expresses that they are asking the question out of curiosity.

> Thank you guys.

We typically edit this type of stuff out, as it doesn't really add to the question.