# How does the community feel about rolling back inconsequential edits?

Tags: discussion, editing

In the past week or so I feel like there have been several/many edits that make very minor diction changes to other user's posts, without changing the semantic content.  Here's a couple examples, though they're a little hard to dig up if they weren't in the "Suggested Edits" review queue.

- ["My" -> "So, my"](https://space.stackexchange.com/revisions/51022/5) and ["There is a printer" -> "There is also a printer"](https://space.stackexchange.com/revisions/51022/4).  I objected to these with a comment on the question mentioning the editor.
- [The word "actually" adds nothing](https://space.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/32754) from the Suggested Edits queue.  I voted to reject, another user approved, and apparently that went through.

The [editing help page](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/editing) doesn't explicitly mention anything about edits that change word choice without being factual corrections.  [The answer to "How to edit colloquial questions"](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1007/11262) indicates at least an individual mod preference for preserving a "user's manner of speech."  This is also my preference, though I also dislike posts bumping up the "active questions" queue when the activity isn't interesting.  (That probably means I *shouldn't* roll back edits like these, because that would also count as activity.)

For clarity:  I'm all for edits, including minor ones, that improve readability and accessibility by e.g. correcting capitalization, adding paragraph breaks, utilizing Markdown formatting, etc.  I think the edits I noted above are truly trivial, and maybe more about linguistic "pet peeves."

What do others think?  Am I totally off-base?  Minor edits in the suggestion queue seem to get approved readily.

Comment: If done by the OP, this is typically done for bumping. I've noticed a lot of this as well recently, apparently due to incredulity that OP's awesum ansur isn't getting more votes.  Sadly, bumping is considered ok on stack exchange. I know I posted a reference to that here in meta a while back, but I can't find it now.

Comment: That "so, my" edit though...I would have rejected it as harmful. That one was clearly just for bumping, and maybe the asker doesn't want to sound illiterate.

Comment: On most sites, such a minor edit should be rejected. If you are going to make edits, clean up the whole post, so it is much improved, and only bumps once. One option is to rollback. Another is to make your own edit for more significant improvement. It can be worth notifying the mods so we can see if it is a pattern of bad behaviour.

Comment: I have seen two edits to my post that at first seemed minor, but when I looked more closely I saw that in each case one of the changes, while well-intentioned *and helpful*, may have been too short in term of characters for the SE system to accept it by a user with a certain level of reputation. It looked like they made additional edits that were trivial but necessary to convince the system that the edit should take place.  I don't know if what you've been seeing falls into that category or not, from your examples, it doesn't look like it.

Comment: I often re-read and edit my posted questions and answers.  Editing is a way to self-improve my writing skills, and to make my SE submissions more readable. I think the problem is that editing is taken as the equivalent of “activity” which rewards the “bumping” game. How about changing the default to denying the “active” designation unless it is specifically requested at the time the edit is submitted? A tick box reading “Request activity designation for this edit” would do the job. It would likely reduce the workload for reviewers as well.

Comment: @Woody that's a big change to how the site's software works and would likely have to be network-wide and take an "act of god" to implement. One would have to demonstrate egregious harm from the current behavior before that would be considered. And there are also very important reasons why any edit is considered activity and gets noticed. It could cause harm in several ways - by making current answers irrelevant or just lowering the quality of the question post. Bumping gets the edit noticed so that in principle it can be vetted by the community.

Comment: @Woody Many of SE's quirks are the way they are in order to guard against bad actors. As a different example of that, see answers to [Will/would it be impossible for me to add a third bounty here? Why was 500 my only choice for #2?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/888/12102) (spoiler alert - gamers of the system are why we can't have nice things)

Comment: Reflecting on the discussion a bit:  I think my examples are really more relevant to what I meant than my words.  I'm 100% in support of folks editing their own words to make them better.  I'm a little bothered by bumping.  I am offended by someone tweaking another person's words without it actually making the post more readable or correct.  also I rolled back "So, my" (etc) and briefly felt bad about it.

Comment: They slightly improved the post which slowly gets it better. Also, seeming minor changes can go a long way. I agree that if you edit a post you should go through all of it. If the edit adds nothing at all, however minor, then, well, there is a reason that is on the list of reasons to reject it. @ErinAnne

Comment: The same user is slowly bumping the question by doing gratituous tag edits every day or so.

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390291/should-i-search-for-posts-to-make-trivial-edits-to) at least as far as trivial edits go