# can I edit tags without popping to the head of the "top questions" list?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I like cross-references, and in life in general I think there should be more of them.

However, when I add a tag to a Stack Exchange question, that question jumps to the top of the list due to the "recent activity" of me having added a tag, even though it did not change the content of the question nor any of its answers.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior?  I want to add tags, but I don't want to spam the site with spurious notifications of non-existent content updates.  Is there such a feature, or do I make "silent tagging" a feature request?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I think that exposing edits by moving them to the top of the active list is the primary way to get other users' eyes on them to ensure that they're appropriate and correct.  Any feature request like "silent tagging" would have to have a way to expose them, and a rationale for why that other way would be better than exposure in the Top Questions by Activity.

The commentary on [this Space Exploration Meta question about inconsequential edits](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3013/how-does-the-community-feel-about-rolling-back-inconsequential-edits) treads some of the same ground in a different context.